# Clicking a mouse based on dwell time / how to code a rolling total of sensor measurements

Tags: sensors, c++, array, mouse

I'm trying to write code that should result in a click of the mouse, based on dwell time. I'm getting data from a gyroscope to move the mouse around. I'm not sure what the best way is to approach this from a coding perspective.

My current thinking in pseudocode is below. Basically it should be a rolling total of the last X sensor measurements, which is then compared to a dwell size/radius variable.

On a high level, what would be a feasible approach? I tried a couple of times with for loops and different code, but didn't get anywhere close. I would really appreciate advice about whether my high-level approach is even feasible. Thank you!

```
update array with sensor measurements for (i =  dwell time) ();
    update sum of the array = + i measurement; - (i - size of the array) measurement at each sensor measurement
if at last element of array
    if sum of the array < dwell radius; click
    loop to the beginning of the array
```

Though I'm not sure if `(i - size of the array) measurement` is even possible to do, since it could result in negative i values.

Comment: where is the Arduino part of your question?

Comment: Well it's using an Arduino board, it is more of a C++ question but I was hoping to find an answer here because people might have dealt with similar issues on other arduino projects. Should ask in the C++ stock exchange?

Comment: you are correct, it is completely a C++ question ... i would start with long button press code ... instead of sensing a button press,  sense stop of motion ... after a time interval, desired event is asserted

Comment: Yes this is what I'm struggling with, how to sense the cessation of motion while working with the gyroscope data. I wait a bit for the suggestions here and then if required post in the other stack exchange.

Comment: that is not the problem you asked about ... please focus your question to the actual problem ... `how to sense cessation of motion?` ... remove all irrelevant references to mouse motion and dwell time